# Remote access options for off-site tech support

Tags: software-recommendation

Thinking of installing elementary OS on a new, internet-only, set of workstations at the office for some of our employees. I've built some barebones PCs and want to take advantage of how lightweight elementary OS is.

Currently, on Windows, we are using Windows Remote Desktop to access employees personal computers and repair them from our remote location. We would like to have the same functionality with our OS change.

Currently, the users just provide us their network ID and ipv4 which allows access. Can this be done in elementary OS and can these workstations be accessed from out-of-network locations like cellular connections and home networks?

Comment: Do you want to connect without the user's intervention, or some kind of manual steps are acceptable?

There's also NoMachine which offers some enterprise-level remote assistance services.
Chrome Remote Desktop could be a way of achieving this by sharing a temporary code that expires after a while, and doesn't require sharing an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as elegant as other solutions but teamviewer has everything you need.

Comment: From the google searches I've done, it appears that it is. Thank you!